# Angular View doesnt update after http interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-services, angular-http-interceptors

I am using promise in controller to render the view after `$http` request. Everything works fine except when the http interceptor gets involved during 401 errors. When that happens, this is the issue I am facing:

1. The http interceptor picks up on the 401 errors from api, adds
   the rejected query to buffer and shows the Login Modal.
2. After the login is successful, the queued api queries that had
   401 before is tried again and the api returns the requested data
   successfully.
3. However what happens is, even when the data is returned from api,
   the angular view is not updated. The view only updates after the
   manually refresh that state.

**These are my codes:**

**1) http interceptor:**

I am using `http-auth-interceptor` in this

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', 'httpBuffer', function($rootScope, $q, httpBuffer) {
          return {
            responseError: function(rejection) {
              if (!rejection.config.ignoreAuthModule) {

                  var rejectionReasons = ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired', 'token_absent', 'token_invalid'];

                  angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function(value, key) {

                       if(rejection.data.error === value) {
                         var deferred = $q.defer();
                         httpBuffer.append(rejection.config, deferred);
                         $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', rejection);
                         return deferred.promise;
                       }
                  })

              }
              // otherwise, default behaviour
              return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
          };
        }]);
```

**2) http interceptor watch:**

```
scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {
    LoginModalService.openLoginModal();
    console.log('login needed');
});
scope.$on('event:auth-loginCancelled', function() {
        $state.go('index');
});
```

**3) Controller:**

```
.controller('FetchData', ['$scope', 'DataService', 
            function($scope, DataService) {

            DataService.fetchNamesList()
            .success(function(names) {
                $scope.namesList = names;
            }).error(function(error) {
            // The login modal should show if auth error occurs
            });         

}])
```

Here, the `DataService.fetchNamesList()` does a get request from api.

If an auth interceptor is triggered for the above, I can see the `$http $_GET` is tried again after succesful login but the `$scope.namesList` is not updating in view.

**What I have thought of so far:**

1) I was thinking of adding an additional `$watch` for the above in order for it to work after http interceptor. I thought of that then I discarded that option since if I have mutliple get requests in one page (like the dashboard), then watching each and every request can go overboard.

2) Manually refresh the ui router state after the login like below. This works but it doesnt help when the view involves a form submit where the completed form will be reset after state reload:

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

So I am sure how to resolve this. Can someone guide me here please....

**EDIT:**
After @ChrisFoster's suggestion in comments, I moved the `return deferred.promise` outside `angular.forEach` and slightly changed the foreach check. This seems to update the view correctly after login. However, now the modal shows for every errors and not just the ones listed in rejectionReasons:

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', 'httpBuffer', function($rootScope, $q, httpBuffer) {
      return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
          if (!rejection.config.ignoreAuthModule) {

              var rejectionReasons = ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired', 'token_absent', 'token_invalid'];

              // Loop through each rejection reason and redirect
              angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function(value, key) {

                   if(!(rejection.data.error === value)) {
                      return $q.reject(rejection);
                   }

              });

              var deferred = $q.defer();
              httpBuffer.append(rejection.config, deferred);
              $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', rejection);
              return deferred.promise;

          }
          // otherwise, default behaviour
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: Your `return deferred.promise` is _inside_ the `angular.forEach`. That means that it's returning inside that function, **not** to the promise handler. You'll need to assign that to a variable outside of the `forEach` function and return that way. I'm not sure if that's your whole problem, but it's part of it :)

Comment: @ChrisFoster I think you are right. When I remove the `return deferred.promise` outside the `forEach` loop the view updates fine. So you have spotted my mistake. However, I am still stuck on how to fix it right. I mean, I slightly changed the foreach so it checks for not-equals and return default behaviour if not proceed with the `deferred.promise`. But when I moved the `deferred.promise` outside foreach, the modal is showing for every 400 errors and not the ones I have listed under rejectionReasons. The defer and promise thing confuses me so much and I dont know the right from wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question with my incorrect attempt. Can you help me please? Still stuck on it :(

Comment: @ChrisFoster Finally I got it working. I had to read the basics and spent sometime learning on the `promise` and `angular forEach`. Later I realised how wrong I was. I have now used a simple `if` statement and processing the `deferred.promise` in that. This seems to work. I have added that as the answer since this is the solution I am using at the moment. Please do let me know if you feel this can be done in a more efficient way. Thank you so much for your comment. Your 50 word comment gave me a wealth of knowledge. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working! I'm glad you were able to figure out what was going on. Your current answer is perfectly fine, but if you'd still like to know how to do it with `angular.forEach` then check out the answer I added below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad to see your answer is working. You can still use `angular.forEach` if you'd like, here is an example of what that would look like:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', 'httpBuffer', function($rootScope, $q, httpBuffer) {
  return {
    responseError: function(rejection) {

      var loginRequired = false;
      var rejectionReasons = [
        'token_not_provided', 'token_expired',
        'token_absent', 'token_invalid'
      ];

      // Loop through each rejection reason
      angular.forEach(rejectionReasons, function(value, key) {
        if (!(rejection.data.error === value)) {
          // Set loginRequired, and check this later
          // We *can't* return here because we are inside a function :)
          loginRequired = true;
        }
      });

      // Create a promise
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if (loginRequired && !rejection.config.ignoreAuthModule) {
        // Display a login module and queue a retry request
        httpBuffer.append(rejection.config, deferred);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', rejection);
      } else {
        // Not a auth error, or ignoreAuthModule is enabled
        // Therefore immediately reject the promise with the fail value
        deferred.reject(rejection);
      }

      // Return the promise
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}]);
```

The reason that you were running into issues with `forEach` is because you pass a function as an argument to `forEach`. When you `return` inside of there, you are returning that value *in the `forEach` function*, **not** in the HTTP interceptor function. Therefore, you have three options:

1. You could use a traditional javascript `for` loop
2. You could use an `if` statement conditional
3. You could use an "external" variable you keep track of

Your example is using the second approach, but if you still wanted to use `angular.forEach` my code above is a demonstration of the third approach. The first approach is possible as well, but slightly less common and a little more messy.

Comment: Perfect. That helped heaps since it made more sense on how to approach this using the `angular.forEach` loop. I will now be changing my codes from the `if` statement to `angular.forEach` again since it will easier to add more reasons to the `rejectionReason` array in the future.  Thank you so much again for showing me this example.

Comment: @neel No problem, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using at the moment which is working:

1) Removed the `angular.forEach` and replaced that with a simple `if` statement. Since I am only checking a few conditions, `if` is not too bad of an alternative I thought.

2) I added `deferred.promise` inside the `if` statement and after that everything worked fine. The view got updated after the login and had no trouble for the controller to continue resolving the data returned from the api.

This is my code:

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', 'httpBuffer',
      function($rootScope, $q, httpBuffer) {
        return {
          responseError: function(rejection) {
            if (!rejection.config.ignoreAuthModule) {

                var rejectionReasons = ['token_not_provided', 'token_expired', 'token_absent', 'token_invalid'];

                // Loop through each rejection reason and redirect
                if (
                      rejection.data.error === 'token_not_provided' ||
                      rejection.data.error === 'token_expired' ||
                      rejection.data.error === 'token_absent' ||
                      rejection.data.error === 'token_invalid'

                    )
                {
                  var deferred = $q.defer();
                  httpBuffer.append(rejection.config, deferred);
                  $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', rejection);
                  return deferred.promise;
                }

            }
            // otherwise, default behaviour
            return $q.reject(rejection);
          }
        };
      }]);
```

Thanks to @ChrisFoster who pointed out the mistake:

> Your return deferred.promise is inside the angular.forEach. That means
>   that it's returning inside that function, not to the promise handler.
>   You'll need to assign that to a variable outside of the forEach
>   function and return that way.